# How to properly cancel MediaPlayer.prepare()?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, illegalstateexception

I am using the Android MediaPlayer to play a Video in my app.

I use `MediaPlayer.prepare()` instead of `MediaPlayer.prepareAsync()` deliberately, because I want to be able to know when the statement is finished so that I can, for example, hide a progress bar.

I realize that I could do this with a `MediaPlayer.prepareAsync()`, but since this would create an ugly overhead in my code, would only be used for this detection and probably wouldn't help in this situation anyway, I don't want to do that.

When I start my activity with the video loading and I try to go back to the previous activity before it finished `MediaPlayer.prepare()`, it throws an `IllegalStateException`.

All the steps I take before that are synchronized, so just catching the Exception and ignoring it would be possible here, however, I don't want to have throwing and catching an Exception as expected behavior if I can avoid it.

I've already tried to call `MediaPlayer.reset()` while `MediaPlayer.prepare()` is running, but the same thing happens.

Comment: Diagram of States  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer .   you can try mediaPlayer.release();

Comment: i dont get how you can `"go back to the previous activity"` while `prepare()` is running thus blocking the main, UI thread? are you using some different thread or what?

Comment: @Beyazidy Thanks for the suggestion but the same thing happens, just like with `reset`. I made sure that it was called by pre- and suffixing both prepare and `reset/release` with debug log. Debug log was as expected: prepare-pre-log; cancel-pre-log; Exception

Comment: @pskink Yes, its run in the `doInBackgrund` of an `AsyncTask`

Comment: Did you try to stop your asynctask when go back previous activity? asyncTask.cancel(true);

Comment: and using that extra  `AsyncTask`  is easier than calling `prepareAsync()` with `OnPreparedListener`? imho, using that `AsyncTask` is asking for troubles only...

Comment: @pskink you are probably right about that. But before I go through the trouble of changing this while being on a impossibly tight schedule, do you know/think that this would fix the problem? Seems to me like an illegal state will still be an illegal state, right? My build is kind of complex since I distinguish between different types of media player wrapper who are derived from a base class but vary in how they operate in different places concerning the media player

Comment: make some quick test with another `MadiaPlayer` that does nothing but calls `prepareAsync()` then try to call `release()` while preparing your data source and see what happens